# If-Else condition in H2 database query

Tags: sql-server, scala, h2

I have a connector application which reads from third-party database using apache camel. I am trying to mock the same database and query operations using H2 database, so that connectivity to the thirdparty database is not required for testing. 
The database is in MS SQL Server. I am using the Mode as SQLServer in my H2 database. However, I have a mssql query with if-else condition. When I try to execute it, I am getting the following error.

MSSQL query is

```
if((SELECT count(*) from Employee where DateCreated < '2016-02-02 00:05:00')>1)
    SELECT TOP 10 * from Employee where DateCreated < '2016-02-02 00:05:00'
  else
    SELECT TOP 1 * from Employee where DateCreated < '2016-02-02 00:05:00'
```

Error Message :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "  IF[*]((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE)>1)
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM EMPLOYEE
  ELSE
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EMPLOYEE "; expected "INSERT, {"; SQL statement:
  if((SELECT count(*) from Employee)>1)
    SELECT TOP 10 * from Employee
  else
    SELECT TOP 1 * from Employee [42001-185]
```

I am assuming that the conditional query is not supported in the H2 database. IS there anyway, I can execute this same query in H2? 
Worst Case, is there any otherway, in which I can change the mssql query which is compatible with H2 ?

Comment: The actual query is too big, so i didnt want to paste it here.  If the condition matches, we need to execute a one query else a different one. To test the scenario, i simply created a simple query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is. You can use the [case](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#case) command in H2 for the if/else effect, and in your application could factor the code that goes into the conditions and/or statements to execute so that you write it and use it in both your ms sql and h2 requests.

Comment: can you elaborate?
the H2 syntax is 
CASE WHEN expression THEN expression ELSE expression END
What the question is asking is how to do
CASE WHEN expression THEN statement ELSE statement END